# How to find UI in code c# (button, Panel etc)

Tags: unity-game-engine, gameobject, unity-ui

in an empty game object i have a selection Manger script. I'm having some difficulties with finding a panel (called: OpenSelection) I created in Canvas.
I would like to find the panel where ever it is in the hierarchy and set enabled to true.

But the code isn't finding the panel. I'm not sure why.

---

any help would be appreciated

```
//UI
private GameObject panel;
 
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    panel = GameObject.Find("OpenSelection");
    panel.SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `Find()` is never the best approach for anything.

Try to set a variable reference to your `OpenSelection`, like you did with your `panel`, then call this variable.

Comment: Extensive usage of Unity's `Find` methods seems to be a plague of people new to Unity or programming in general. Looking through questions here, they're used very often. I always wonder - should it be pointed out as a side note when answering, even if the question is about something else? Like: "here's your answer, and by the way you should be doing (...) rather than using `Find`".

Answer (score 0):

GameObject.Find() only returns active GameObject. Here you are trying to find the OpenSelection panel which is not active. That's why  the Find() is not finding the OpenSelection panel.